# C++ overload bool operator

Tags: c++, boolean, operator-overloading

I am new to overloading operators. I am trying to overload a bool operator. I am currently using the bool operator as an access function into the Date class. Any suggestions how I would go about converting the bool EqualTo function to overload the operator? Thank you!

```
class Date {
private:
    int mn;        //month component of a date
    int dy;        //day component of a date
    int yr;        //year comonent of a date

public:
    //constructors
    Date() : mn(0), dy(0), yr(0)
    {}
    Date(int m, int d, int y) : mn(m), dy(d), yr(y)
    {}

    //access functions

    int getDay() const
    {
        return dy;
    }
    int getMonth() const
    {
        return mn;
    }
    int getYear() const
    {
        return yr;
    }

    bool EqualTo(Date d) const;

};

bool Date::EqualTo(Date d) const
{
    return (mn == d.mn) && (dy == d.dy) && (yr == d.yr);
}
```

Comment: Change the declaration to `operator bool() const`. But you don't want that. You want to create `friend operator==(const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs)`.

Comment: Looks more like you are trying to overload `operator==` to compare two objects?

Comment: Why are you trying to overload `operator bool()`? You seem to be comparing 2 `Date`s, so you should probably overload `operator==`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that it will be an array of Dates.

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with checking if 2 dates are equal?

Comment: @larry718 That doesn't change the fact that you want the equality operator and not the bool conversion.

Comment: There is a quite extensive answer about operator overloading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading).

Answer (score 5):

The implementation of your `EqualTo` function suggests that you should be overloading `operator==` to test if 2 `Date` objects are equal. All you have to do is rename `EqualTo` to `operator==`. And you should take the arguments by `const&`.

```
bool Date::operator==(Date const &d) const
{
    return (mn == d.mn) && (dy == d.dy) && (yr == d.yr);
}
```

Inside the class `Date`, the declaration would look like:

```
bool operator==(Date const &d) const;
```

Another way to do this is to make the operator a friend of the class:

```
friend bool operator==(Date const &a, Date const &b) const
{
    return (a.mn == b.mn) && (a.dy == b.dy) && (a.yr == b.yr);
}
```

Note that in this case, this is *not* a member function. In this case, you can define it inside the class (where you need the friend keyword).

If you define a `friend` function outside the class, you still need to declare it as a `friend` within the class. However, the definition can no longer have the `friend` keyword.

I would also recommend naming your variables a bit more clearly, such as `month`, `day`, and `year`.

Comment: Great! How would I declare in Date?

Comment: Added more explanation.

Comment: I implemented the first example into my code. Now I am getting an error - "Out-of-line definition of 'operator==' does not match any declaration in 'Date'"

Comment: @cigen the declaration is usually marked as friend ;) Its worth mentioning that these should be public member functions, and that const can be placed on either side ;)

Comment: @Waqar Yes, it's in the answer. Is it not clear enough? Edited a bit.

Comment: @cigien its clear. Just one more thing I think, if you declare the friend function inside the class, then definition outside the class cannot have `friend` in its signature.